# Unable to detect ibeacon with android beacon library

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

I am not able to detect ibeacon presence with the android beacon library. This is my code

```
BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        if (beaconManager != null && !beaconManager.isBound(this)) {
            beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                    setBeaconLayout("m:0-3=4c000215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
            beaconManager.bind(this);
```

And in the onBeaconServiceConnect method

```
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
                for (Beacon beacon : beacons) {
                    Log.i("MainActivity", "I see a beacon that is about "+beacon.getDistance()+" meters away.");
                    System.out.print("Beacon seen"+ beacon.getId1());
                }
            }
        });

        try {
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));
        } catch (RemoteException e) {    }
    }
```

I also added this permissions in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

In the output

```
16:59:26.571 3571-3571/com.example.kev.altbeacon W/BluetoothCrashResolver: Can't read macs from BluetoothCrashResolverState.txt
04-23 16:59:26.581 3571-3571/com.example.kev.altbeacon W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
04-23 16:59:26.581 3571-3571/com.example.kev.altbeacon W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
04-23 16:59:26.581 3571-3571/com.example.kev.altbeacon E/MonitoringStatus: Deserialization exception, message: $s
04-23 16:59:26.621 3571-3635/com.example.kev.altbeacon D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so
04-23 16:59:26.641 3571-3635/com.example.kev.altbeacon D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x7f8787f178
04-23 16:59:26.641 3571-3635/com.example.kev.altbeacon I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-23 16:59:26.641 3571-3635/com.example.kev.altbeacon D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1440x2560]-format:1
04-23 16:59:26.651 3571-3571/com.example.kev.altbeacon W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
04-23 16:59:26.651 3571-3635/com.example.kev.altbeacon D/libGLESv1: DTS_GLAPI : DTS is not allowed for Package : com.example.kev.altbeacon
04-23 16:59:26.761 3571-3571/com.example.kev.altbeacon I/InjectionManager: dispatchCreateOptionsMenu :com.example.kev.altbeacon.MainActivity
04-23 16:59:26.761 3571-3571/com.example.kev.altbeacon I/InjectionManager: dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu :com.example.kev.altbeacon.MainActivity
04-23 16:59:26.761 3571-3571/com.example.kev.altbeacon D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
04-23 16:59:26.791 3571-3571/com.example.kev.altbeacon I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@bf0208c time:27543539
04-23 16:59:27.881 3571-3571/com.example.kev.altbeacon D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
04-23 16:59:27.881 3571-3571/com.example.kev.altbeacon D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
04-23 16:59:27.881 3571-3571/com.example.kev.altbeacon D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
04-23 16:59:27.881 3571-3571/com.example.kev.altbeacon D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
04-23 16:59:27.881 3571-3571/com.example.kev.altbeacon D/BluetoothLeScanner: could not find callback wrapper
04-23 16:59:28.991 3571-3571/com.example.kev.altbeacon D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
04-23 16:59:28.991 3571-3571/com.example.kev.altbeacon D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
04-23 16:59:28.991 3571-3571/com.example.kev.altbeacon D/BluetoothLeScanner: could not find callback wrapper
04-23 16:59:30.101 3571-3571/com.example.kev.altbeacon D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
04-23 16:59:30.101 3571-3571/com.example.kev.altbeacon D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
04-23 16:59:30.101 3571-3571/com.example.kev.altbeacon D/BluetoothLeScanner: could not find callback wrapper
04-23 16:59:31.241 3571-3571/com.example.kev.altbeacon D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
```

I tried the code with two different phones and it's not working on anyone of them. This output is when I try the code with a Samsung S6. With a Samsung s4 I don't get this state-ok/ could not found... messages, I got just this

```
04-23 17:09:22.290 26020-26020/com.example.kev.altbeacon I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1034a987 time:6819065
04-23 17:09:36.083 26020-26020/com.example.kev.altbeacon V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{1a3840b9 token=android.os.BinderProxy@1034a987 {com.example.kev.altbeacon/com.example.kev.altbeacon.MainActivity}} show : true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few tips:

- If your devices have Android 6+, you must ensure you have Location Permission granted as described here: http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2015/09/29/is-your-beacon-app-ready-for-android-6.html
- Try the off-the-shelf [Locate app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en) that uses this same library.  If that app can't detect the beacons, there may be an issue with the beacon transmitters themselves.
- Make sure Location is turned on in Settings.
- Make sure Bluetooth is turned on in Settings.

Comment: Thank you. I granted the permission as described in the link and it worked. Also the location was enabled but not in for the app.